# Linking MASM-program with link results in error to load mspdbcore.dll (error code: 193)

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, masm, masm32

> Linking MASM-program with link results in error to load mspdbcore.dll (error code: 193)

When building assembly programs in Visual Studio 2015 there are no problems. However, doing the steps manually, produces the linker error seen below.

I've already found the mspdbcore.dll in the VC-directory on the system and added this directory to the Path, but it doesn't solve the problems.

I can't seem to locate what's wrong, and I hope someone is capable of guiding me in the right direction.

The system is Windows 10 64-bit version.

```
C:\Users\nlykkei\Desktop>ml /c /coff Hello.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: Hello.asm

C:\Users\nlykkei\Desktop>link /subsystem:windows /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib Hello.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1171: unable to load mspdbcore.dll (error code: 193)
```

The Hello.asm program:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

.stack 4096

extrn MessageBoxA@16 : PROC

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data 
MsgBoxCaption db "Win32 Assembly", 0
MsgBoxText db "Hello World!", 0

.code
Hello_ PROC
    push 0
    push offset MsgBoxCaption
    push offset MsgBoxText
    push 0
    call MessageBoxA@16

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
Hello_ ENDP
END Hello_
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: You also need to have the directory where `msobj140.dll` is located (`Common7\IDE`) in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @HansPassant where are the user32.lib and kernel32.lib files stored? The linker works perfectly using /defaultlib:user32.lib etc, but I'm curious where to find these files myself. A quick system search shows nothing.

Comment: In the Windows SDK directory.  The LIB environment variable points to it.

Comment: But they are in uppercase like "Kernel32.Lib" and "User32.Lib", why?

Comment: I uppercase the first letters of my name as well.  Casing of filenames is quite irrelevant on Windows.

Comment: Ahh, I thought kernel32.lib and Kernel32.Lib was seen as two different files..... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed have the **mspdbcore.dll** and **mspdb140.dll** files in the correct places, and your path appears correct.

Somehow my system was pulling this
`PATH=".;D:\\p4\\dk\\win\\VC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86"`
Instead of the fixed:
`PATH=".;D:\\p4\\dk\\win\\VC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX64"`

Try rebooting your computer, because oddly enough, that solved the issue for me after pulling-my-hair-out for an hour.